# How can remove space between buttons in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

I find there are space between the btnToEmail and btnToDelete, I have set android:layout_marginLeft="0dp".
How can remove space between buttons in RelativeLayout? Thanks!
[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="3dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:background="#DCDCDC" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnToEmail"
            style="@style/myTextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/export" />

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnToDelete"
            style="@style/myTextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnToEmail"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:text="@string/delete" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSet"
            style="@style/myTextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnToDelete"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:text="@string/settings" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAbout"
            style="@style/myTextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnSet"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:text="@string/about" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnExit"
            style="@style/myTextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/exit" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what about `marginRight`?

Comment: try a negative value if 0 is still giving a gap.  i.e -10dp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in `Button` background. Default background is the following (file `btn_default.xml` in platform resources):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_focused" />
    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable" />
</selector>
```

All items are 9patches like the following (e.g. btn_default_normal.9.png from above selector):

[image: btn_default_normal.9.png]

As You can see, it includes paddings. So, I would suggest to use Your own backgrounds (or modify platform backgrounds and remove paddings using [9patch tool](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You can give in negative values in margins,but that is not recommended. If you're eventually gonna use a png instead of button you can try with scaleType parameter.(something like fitXY)